Incorrect Query Structure for API Call
Api call from dazzer api for Atist Profile, but data does not loading ArtistProfle RecyclerView
`artistProfileRecyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewArtist)
artistProfileRecyclerView.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this@DashBoardActivity)
artistArrayList= arrayListOf()
    artistProfileRecyclerView.adapter=ArtistsProfileAdapter(artistArrayList,this@DashBoardActivity)


    // Retrofit API call for artist profiles
    val retrofitBuilderArtist=Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://deezerdevs-deezer.p.rapidapi.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(ArtistProfileApiInterface::class.java)

    //call the API to get artist data

    val retrofitArtistData=retrofitBuilderArtist.getProductData("artist")

    retrofitArtistData.enqueue(object :Callback<MyData>{
        override fun onResponse(call  : Call<MyData>, response: Response<MyData>) {
            val artistsProfileDataList=response.body()?.data ?:return

            for (artist in artistsProfileDataList){

                val artistName=artist.title
                val artistImage=artist.album.cover_medium

                val artistsProfile=ArtistsProfile(artistName,artistImage)
                artistArrayList.add(artistsProfile)
            }
            artistProfileRecyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<MyData>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("TAG: onFailure", "onFailure: "+t.message)
        }
    })`

Logcat showing error 2024-10-22 18:41:48.891  7480-7480  RecyclerView            com.example.musicplayer              E  No adapter attached; skipping layout 2024-10-22 18:41:48.891  7480-7480  RecyclerView            com.example.musicplayer              E  No adapter attached; skipping layout 2024-10-22 18:41:48.892  7480-7480  RecyclerView            com.example.musicplayer              E  No adapter attached; skipping layout 2024-10-22 18:41:53.850   409-409   android.ha...rvice-mock and....power.stats@1.0-service.mock  E  Failed to getEnergyData
i am trying to fetch the artist profile data from dazzer api enter image description here

Is there any thing printed by the Log statement? If yes, then please do add that too, it will help.

Here are few things you can try: (1) First check whether the API call returns data or not, (2) Is your artistArrayList properly populated with data, (3) Is your recycler view visible to the screen.

2024-10-22 18:41:48.891  7480-7480  RecyclerView            com.example.musicplayer              E  No adapter attached; skipping layout 2024-10-22 18:41:48.891  7480-7480  RecyclerView            com.example.musicplayer              E  No adapter attached; skipping layout 2024-10-22 18:41:48.892  7480-7480  RecyclerView            com.example.musicplayer              E  No adapter attached; skipping layout 2024-10-22 18:41:53.850   409-409   android.ha...rvice-mock and....power.stats@1.0-service.mock  E  Failed to getEnergyData

As I can see in the logs and from the code, You are creating adapter and updating artistArrayList, but you are not attaching the adapter to the recyclerview. Doing that will solve your problem
